# populate access form via sql in vba

Tags: sql, database, forms, ms-access, vba

I have a continuous form that i would like to populate via a sql select statement in my VBA script. I can't seem to make this work:

```
sel = "Select * from table1 where  a = 10;"
Set SQL = db.OpenRecordset(sel)
SQL.Requery
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you put your select instruction in the recordsource property of the form?

```
Me.recordsource = "Select * from table1 where  a = 10;"
```

if your script is in one of the form's procedures, or

```
myForm.recordsource = "Select * from table1 where  a = 10;"
```

if your script is in an independant module

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a Recordset instead of just setting the `RecordSource` (like already suggested in [Philippe Grondier's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9180319/6884)), you can also do this:

```
Set Me.Recordset = db.OpenRecordset("select ...")
```

I must admit that setting the `RecordSource` is the "standard way" (especially if you already have a SQL statement and want to populate the form with that), but I still wanted to show this alternative solution.
I usually use it to populate a form with a Recordset that is returned by a function.

Comment: Totally right, and this is also the way I do it, though I systematically use ADODB instead of DAO recordsets.

Comment: Yes, me too (we're using Access as a SQL Server frontend)